# After upgrade static content is set with out pub/

Tags: magento2, design, static-content, static-content-deploy

```
<html lang="en">
    <head >
        <script>
    var BASE_URL = 'http://mage.test/';
    var require = {
        "baseUrl": "http://mage.test/static/version1561748846/frontend/Brent/default/en_US"
    };
```

My base URL on the prod site looks like this

```
/pub/static/version1561138892/frontend/Brent/default/en_US
```

I am not sure where the Base URL is stuck?

My doc root is set here

/Users/brent/sites/mage

I can reference a file to /Users/brent/sites/mage/info.php

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this on your test site, it's looking like your test site is now serving the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` from the `pub` directory, which would be why it's removed from the urls.

How is your test site configured? Have any changes happened to the apache/nginx virtual hosts and where they serve the site from?

Comment: I am using Valet Plus. I have not changed my document root.